# Hide Part Of text In same <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say for example, I have the following code

```html
<p class="text-content">
"First part of text"
<span id="divider"></span>
"Second part of text"
</p>
```

How do I hide the second part of the text?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way instead of putting the second part of the text in a <span> or similar?

Answer (score 3):

JS implementation:

```js
document.getElementById("divider").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("divider").nextSibling);
```

```html
<p class="text-content">
"First part of text"
<span id="divider"></span>
"Second part of text"
</p>
```

This will remove the immediate next node after the divider.

If you want all the elements and nodes after the divider to be removed:

```js
while (document.getElementById("divider").nextSibling || document.getElementById("divider").nextElementSibling) {
  if (document.getElementById("divider").nextSibling) {
    document.getElementById("divider").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("divider").nextSibling);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("divider").nextElementSibling.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="text-content">
  "First part of text"
  <div id="divider"></div>
  text node
  <p>paragrah</p>
  <span>text in span</span>
  text node
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<p class="text-content">
"First part of text"
<span id="divider"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: I want it done with javascript or css. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a divider consider putting the text inside the span

```html
<p class="text-content">
"First part of text"
<span>"Second part of text"</span>
</p>
```

with that you can now use either css or javascript on it like so:

css:

```css
.text-content span {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text-content span");
text.style.display = "none";
```

If you have multiple instances of this you can use an id instead of a class like usual and hide it based on events or certain conditions as you please.